# Automatically switch basemap at zoomlevel?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, dom-events

I am trying to make leaflet change the basemap depending on the zoomlevel. What I am trying:
(I am new to coding)
I am receiving an error statement:

> SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

I did check the syntax several time but cant find the error.

I also wonder if there is a more elegant way to write it, instead of that double if-else statement.

```
map.addEventListener("zoomend", changeBasemap);

function changeBasemap() {
    var zoomLevel = map.getZoom();
    if (zoomLevel < 5) {
        if (map.hasLayer(osm)) {
            map.removeLayer(osm);
            stamen_Watercolor.addTo(map);
        } else {
            console.log(no need to change basemap)
        }
    } else { 
        if (map.hasLayer(stamen_Watercolor)) {
            map.removeLayer(stamen_Watercolor);
            osm.addTo(map);
        } else {
            console.log(no need to change basemap);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your root problem is covered by Leaflet's `minZoom`/`maxZoom` functionality on `L.TileLayer`s, no need to manually check for it. As for locating syntax errors, try a linting tool such as https://prettier.io/playground/

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Missing_parenthesis_after_argument_list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because you forgot quotes in:

```
console.log(no need to change basemap);
```

Correct it to:

```
console.log("no need to change basemap");
```

Here's a suggestion about how your code could look cleaner:

```
function changeBasemap() 
{
    if ( map.getZoom() < 5 && map.hasLayer(osm) ) {
        map.removeLayer(osm);
        stamen_Watercolor.addTo(map);
        return;
    }

    if ( map.getZoom() > 4 && map.hasLayer(stamen_Watercolor) ) {
        map.removeLayer(stamen_Watercolor);
        osm.addTo(map);
        return;
    }

    console.log("no need to change basemap");
}
```